# Refresh table guestbook

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm continuing my Guestbook and I was wondering if there is a method to refresh the table when there is a new message.

All posts are stored in a database and are shown in a html table:

```
 echo "<table class=\"guestbook\" cellspacing='10'>";

        while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $avatar = $Database->selectAvatar($rows['name']);
            $rowsAvatar=mysql_fetch_array($avatar)

            ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="avatar" width="10%"><img class="circolare" src="<?php echo $rowsAvatar['avatar'] ?>"></td>
            <td class="name" width="10%"><?php echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
            <td class="datetime" width="20%"><?php echo $rows['datetime']; ?></td>
            <td class="comment" width="50%"><div class="scrollbar"><?php echo $rows['comment']; ?></div></td>
            <td class="delete" width="10%"><?php
                if($rows['name']== $name){
                    echo "<a href=\"deletecomment.php?comment_id=" .  $rows['id'] ."\">Delete it</a>";
                }
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>


        <?php
        }
        echo "</table >";
        ?>
```

I want to update this table automatically, how can I do?
Firstly I tried to use an automatic refresh every 5 seconds but there is the problem that if the user it's writing a post (the form it's in the same page) and the page refresh it will be lost.
I think I have to use ajax, am I right? Any suggestion?

I'm trying to implement it with ajax and I wrote this

```
window.onload = function(){
    interval = window.setInterval('updateGuest()',5000);
}



function updateGuest() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getGuest.php',
        method: 'get',
        success: on_getGuest_success,
        error: on_error
    });
}

function on_getGuest_success(data) {
    for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++) {
       //do something
    }

}

function on_error() {
   //do something

}
```

getGuest.php

```
<?php

include("Database.php");

$Database = new Database( "localhost", "root", "1234");
$Database->connectToServer();
$Database->connectToDatabase("test");

$result = $Database->selectQuery("guestbook", "*");

$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

I've included all scripts in Home.php (where the guestbook is)

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.11.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: `it seems it doesn't work, why?` what doesn't? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @Peter sorry, there was stupid error like datalength instead of data.length ecc.. How can I generate the table to view in Home.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery to check every few seconds if there is a new post (by using a [`get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) or [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call).

If there is a new post, you could [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) it to the table. That way the page won't have to refresh, and the person writing a post can continue.

If you are not familiar with the mentioned techniques, I recommend you look them up and try to implement them, since they are often used.

Comment: I don't know, I've studied something about ajax but when I used it (for university) it was with Java. I've updated the first post, I started writing something with ajax, check it out!